# Convert a list with strings all to lowercase or uppercase

Tags: python, list

I have a Python list variable that contains strings. Is there a function that can convert all the strings in one pass to lowercase and vice versa, uppercase?

Comment: Why "in one pass"? Do you contemplate the possibility of it taking multiple passes?

Answer (score 661, accepted):

It can be done with [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> [x.lower() for x in ["A", "B", "C"]]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> [x.upper() for x in ["a", "b", "c"]]
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

or with the [`map` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), ["A", "B", "C"]))
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(map(lambda x: x.upper(), ["a", "b", "c"]))
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: Second proposition with **map** is correct but wasteful. There is **no point in making a lambda function**. Just use `map(str.lower, ["A","B","C"])`

Comment: When I try to print a list after this call nothing changes. Why is that?

Comment: @mimic A bit late, but for people coming across this, I'm guessing your issue was probably that you were not assigning the result of the list comprehension back to your list. Just doing to the list comprehension returns the value, but does not reassign it to the list variable.

Comment: What is the fastest between the two? (list comprehension vs map)

Comment: @ThePhi I did a quick check using a small sample I have. Doing a loop on my 20 lists with around 500 items each. The fastest was the former (avg. 0.0011s) vs using map (avg. 0.0022s).

Answer (score 74):

```
>>> list(map(str.lower,["A","B","C"]))
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: obviously `str.upper` to convert to uppercase

Comment: In Python 3 you need to pass the resulting map to the list function to get the desired result, that is, `list(map(str.lower,["A","B","C"]))`.

Answer (score 68):

Besides being easier to read (for many people), list comprehensions win the speed race, too:

```
$ python2.6 -m timeit '[x.lower() for x in ["A","B","C"]]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 usec per loop
$ python2.6 -m timeit '[x.upper() for x in ["a","b","c"]]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 usec per loop

$ python2.6 -m timeit 'map(str.lower,["A","B","C"])'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 usec per loop
$ python2.6 -m timeit 'map(str.upper,["a","b","c"])'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 usec per loop

$ python2.6 -m timeit 'map(lambda x:x.lower(),["A","B","C"])'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.87 usec per loop
$ python2.6 -m timeit 'map(lambda x:x.upper(),["a","b","c"])'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.87 usec per loop
```

Comment: Do you know the reason behind why a list comprehension is faster than map?

Comment: It isn't always faster.  Here's an example where it's not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map  But it's not *much* slower in that case.  Using a lambda obviously makes a big difference.  There are more examples of why it's dangerous to trust your intuition on performance issues, especially in Python.

Comment: in python 3, `map` wins the race, but does nothing :)

Comment: @NedDeily `map(str.lower,["A","B","C"])` is fastest is python3.7.5

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL because `map` doesn't do anything besides create an object that does the `.lower()` when you *iterate* over it. If you try `list(map())` it's slower. Just as Jean-François said.

Answer (score 22):

List comprehension is how I'd do it, it's the "Pythonic" way. The following transcript shows how to convert a list to all upper case then back to lower:

```
pax@paxbox7:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> x = ["one", "two", "three"] ; x
['one', 'two', 'three']

>>> x = [element.upper() for element in x] ; x
['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']

>>> x = [element.lower() for element in x] ; x
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Comment: err, using `list` as a variable name isn't the best choice :)

Comment: No but, since the name is of little importance to the method being shown, it's not really relevant. However, I'll change the name in case someone wants to use the code as is.

Comment: the magic of stackoverflow: 250 votes for a python 2-only solution using lambda where it shouldn't!! well 249 now

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, not sure why you think this is this a Python-2-only solution. As the transcripts shows, it's *clearly* running under Python 3.5.2. In fact, I just checked it *again* for confirmation. ... some time passes while I investigate ... Actually, never mind, it appears you were talking about the current accepted answer rather than this one, so you probably should be commenting *there* rather than here. No doubt an honest mistake. Cheers.

Comment: yeah, I wasn't criticizing yours (apart from the `list` stuff :)).Where do you think the UV you recently got comes from ? :)

Answer (score 7):

For this sample the comprehension is fastest

```
$ python -m timeit -s 's=["one","two","three"]*1000' '[x.upper for x in s]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 809 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s 's=["one","two","three"]*1000' 'map(str.upper,s)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.12 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s 's=["one","two","three"]*1000' 'map(lambda x:x.upper(),s)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.77 msec per loop
```

Answer (score 7):

a student asking, another student with the same problem answering :))

```
fruits=['orange', 'grape', 'kiwi', 'apple', 'mango', 'fig', 'lemon']
newList = []
for fruit in fruits:
    newList.append(fruit.upper())
print(newList)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
mylist = ['Mixed Case One', 'Mixed Case Two', 'Mixed Three']
print(list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), mylist)))
print(list(map(lambda x: x.upper(), mylist)))
```

Answer (score 6):

A much simpler version of the top answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42128202/6069097) by @Amorpheuses.

With a list of values in val:

```
valsLower = [item.lower() for item in vals]
```

This worked well for me with an f = open() text source.

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is to matching with another string by converting in one pass, you can use `str.casefold()` as well.

This is useful when you have non-ascii characters and matching with ascii versions(eg: maße vs masse).Though `str.lower` or `str.upper` fails in such cases, `str.casefold()` will pass. 
This is available in Python 3 and the idea is discussed in detail with the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31599276/4848659.

```
>>>str="Hello World";
>>>print(str.lower());
hello world
>>>print(str.upper());
HELLO WOLRD
>>>print(str.casefold());
hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using:

```
my_list = ['india', 'america', 'china', 'korea']

def capitalize_list(item):
    return item.upper()

print(list(map(capitalize_list, my_list)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution to the problem, but I don't recommend using it. Just putting it here for completion of this topic since this solution wasn't added before.

```
import timeit

def foo1():
    L = ["A", "B", "C", "&"]
    return [x.lower() for x in L]
def foo2():
    L = ["A", "B", "C", "&"]
    return "%".join(L).lower().split("%")

for i in range(10):
    print("foo1", timeit.timeit(foo1, number=100000))
    print("foo2", timeit.timeit(foo2, number=100000), end="\n\n")
```

- 

```
foo1 0.0814619
foo2 0.058695300000000006

foo1 0.08401910000000004
foo2 0.06001100000000004

foo1 0.08252670000000001
foo2 0.0601641

foo1 0.08721100000000004
foo2 0.06254229999999994

foo1 0.08776279999999992
foo2 0.05946070000000003

foo1 0.08383590000000007
foo2 0.05982449999999995

foo1 0.08354679999999992
foo2 0.05930219999999997

foo1 0.08526650000000013
foo2 0.060690699999999875

foo1 0.09940110000000013
foo2 0.08484609999999981

foo1 0.09921800000000003
foo2 0.06182889999999985
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
>>> s = []
>>> p = ['This', 'That', 'There', 'is', 'apple']
>>> [s.append(i.lower()) if not i.islower() else s.append(i) for i in p]
>>> s
>>> ['this', 'that', 'there', 'is','apple']
```

This solution will create a separate list containing the lowercase items, regardless of their original case. If the original case is upper then the `list s` will contain lowercase of the respective item in `list p`. If the original case of the list item is already lowercase in `list p` then the `list s` will retain the item's case and keep it in lowercase. Now you can use `list s` instead of `list p`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert all string to lowercase in the list, You can use pandas :

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['Study', 'Insights']

pd_d = list(pd.Series(data).str.lower())
```

output:

```
['study', 'insights']
```