# How to change a string into uppercase?

Tags: python, string, function, uppercase, string-conversion

How can I convert a string into uppercase in Python?

When I tried to research the problem, I found something about `string.ascii_uppercase`, but it couldn't solve the problem:

```
>>> s = 'sdsd'
>>> s.ascii_uppercase
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ascii_uppercase'
```

---

<sub>See [How do I lowercase a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/) for the opposite.</sub>

Comment: Easy tutorial on doing this: http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/python-scripting-tutorial/strings-tutorial.php

Comment: Related: [How to convert string to lowercase in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6797984/95735) :)

Answer (score 1332, accepted):

Use [`str.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper):

```
>>> s = 'sdsd'
>>> s.upper()
'SDSD'
```

See [String Methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

Comment: Also worth mentioning `title()`, `'abc def'.title()` will give you `Abc Def`

Comment: It works for char type as well. Thank you for your helpful answer.

Comment: @yvesBaumes what do you mean by "char type"? Python does not have chars. Only strings with length of 1

Comment: *Please Note:* The `.upper()` and `.lower()` functions do not modify the original `str` i.e. use `s = s.upper()` for effective results

Answer (score 100):

To get upper case version of a string you can use [`str.upper`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper):

```
s = 'sdsd'
s.upper()
#=> 'SDSD'
```

On the other hand [`string.ascii_uppercase`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase) is a string containing all ASCII letters in upper case:

```
import string
string.ascii_uppercase
#=> 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Answer (score 20):

to make the string upper case -- just simply type

```
s.upper()
```

simple and easy! you can do the same to make it lower too

```
s.lower()
```

etc.

Answer (score 18):

```
s = 'sdsd'
print (s.upper())
upper = raw_input('type in something lowercase.')
lower = raw_input('type in the same thing caps lock.')
print upper.upper()
print lower.lower()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @HCode! It is customary to add some commentary to your code.

Answer (score 7):

for making uppercase from lowercase to upper
just use

```
"string".upper()
```

where `"string"` is  your string that you want to convert uppercase

for this question  concern it will like this:

```
s.upper()
```

for making lowercase from uppercase string
just use

```
"string".lower()
```

where `"string"` is  your string that you want to convert lowercase

for this question concern it will like this:

```
s.lower()
```

If you want to make your whole string variable use

```
s="sadf"
# sadf

s=s.upper()
# SADF
```

Answer (score 5):

For questions on simple string manipulation the `dir` built-in function comes in handy. It gives you, among others, a list of methods of the argument, e.g., `dir(s)` returns a list containing `upper`.

Answer (score 0):

For converting the string into uppercase

```
s = 'capital letters'

s.upper()

>>> 'CAPITAL LETTERS'
```

For converting only first letter of each word into capital in a sentence

```
s = 'this is a sentence'

str.title(s)

>>> 'This Is A Sentence'
```

Comment: This does not answer the question "How can I convert a string into uppercase in Python?"

Answer (score -1):

You can use [**capitalize()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) to make the 1st letter uppercase as shown below:

```py
test = "this is a sentence."

print(test.capitalize()) # Here
```

Output:

```
This is a sentence.
```