# How would I check if 'a' is in 'b'? Need assistance

Tags: python

I'm tasked with doing this assignment in class, (I'm making code that checks if a password a user puts in follows guidelines).

A portion of this requires me to check if for example A is in B, but I'm having trouble. Here's a portion of the code, how would I check if an uppercase letter is in the password inputted? Sorry, I'm new to python and I'm trying to learn new concepts!

I looked online but what people are saying to put is a bit to complicated for me (as of now).

```
def valid_password(pw):
    up = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWY'
    if pw in up
      return True
```

Comment: up:'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWY' that doesn't work:

Comment: Is that your real code? Because that is not valid Python syntax.

Comment: No, I was just putting that to ask how I would check if PW is in a set range of #'s, letters, or words. I've learned plenty of other concepts but I absolutely forgot I would do something like this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257094/how-to-change-a-string-into-uppercase

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method

Comment: Hint: you have to scan over the characters in the password and check each one against up = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWYZ'. You might want to have a function by itself just for that check.

Comment: FireFume, you can easily fix that, read about variable assignment in Python. Don't forget the else condition if the string is not on 'up'

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't forgetting the else. The assignment requires alot of nested if statements though, so I'm trying to make sure each concept is right before putting it together!

Comment: `pw in up` means to check if the entire password matches a substring of the alphabet. It will be true if `pw = 'CDE'`, for instance. Is that what you're trying to check?

Answer (score 2):

Use `any` in combination with a comprehension:

```
>>> pw1 = "abcd"
>>> pw2 = "abcD"
>>> any(c.isupper() for c in pw1)
False
>>> any(c.isupper() for c in pw2)
True
```

`c.isupper()` evaluates to either `True` or `False` for each of the characters in the string. The syntax `expr for var in iterable` is called a generator comprehension and is an iterable. `any` takes an iterable and tells you whether any of its elements are `True`.

Given that, you can construct a function:

```
def valid_password(pw):
    return any(c.isupper() for c in pw)
```

Answer (score 1):

If its just to check if pw has any uppercase characters, this method should work.

```
import re
def valid_password(pw):
   pattern = re.compile(r'[A-Z]')
   if pattern.findall(pw):
       return True
   else:
       return False
```

Answer (score 0):

`if pw in up` would not make sense in your current context, as conceptually you are checking if the entire password string `pw` is found as a substring in `up`. What you want to check is if any character found within `pw` is in `up`.

```
def valid_password(pw):
    up = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWY'
    for letter in pw:
       if letter in up:
          return True
```

alternatively there is a built in 'isupper'

```
def valid_password(pw):
    for letter in pw:
       if letter.isupper():
          return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's not forget the wonder that is the `string` module:

```
import string

def valid_password(pw):
    return any(c in string.ascii_uppercase for c in pw)
```

This is almost English already, but this checks to see if `any` `c`haracters `in` the `p`ass`w`ord are `in` the collection of uppercase letters (`string.ascii_uppercase`) and returns `True` if any are and `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situation best answer is regular expression look ahead and look behind.
Take example i need to validate a password with below criteria.

1. password must contains at-least 1 capital letter.
   here is the code

```
def valid_password(password):
    import re
    exp = r'(?=[A-Z]{1,}).*'
    match = re.search(exp, password)
    if match.group() :
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(valid_password("A1ybhcdhhj"))
```

Source : https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html