# I need to print the first three letters of each item in the list in capitals

Tags: python

```
items = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Eggfruit", "Fig"]
for word in items:
      print(word[:3])
#This is for getting the first three characters

items = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Eggfruit", "Fig"]
out = map(lambda x:x.upper(), items)
output =  list(out)
print(output)
#This is to get everything in capitals
```

The first code is for printing the first three characters of each item in the list and the second part prints all the items in capitals-i am not sure what code i need to print the first three characters of each item in capitals

Comment: Why not call `upper()` after slicing? `for word in items: print(word[:3].upper())`

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help :)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change a string into uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257094/how-to-change-a-string-into-uppercase)

Comment: It does answer my question and yes i used some websites for help such as the website geeksforgeeks but i wasn't sure how to get round to it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`word[:3]` is a string of the first three letters, and you can use its `upper` method directly.

```
items = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Eggfruit", "Fig"]
for word in items:
      print(word[:3].upper())
```

There is almost never a reason to use `map`, `filter` or `reduce`. The first two are just functional equivalents of list comprehensions and the latter is also done by `itertools.accumulate`. They only exist because some language committers like the functional approach of other languages.