# How to convert Uppercase Words in a List into lowercase?

Tags: python

I got a text file with 850 lines of different questions about a topic.

All are written in lowercase.

My final goal is to have a text file, where everything is written in uppercase except the stopwords AND words the Questions start with.

For now, I just don't know how I can convert the found words into lowercase

```
# List of Stopwords
import os
import codecs
# open working directory
stopwords = open("C:\\Python Project\\Headings Generator\\stopwords.txt", "r" ,encoding='utf8',errors="ignore")

stopwordsList = [(line.strip()).title() for line in stopwords]

questions = open("C:\\Python Project\\Headings Generator\\questionslist.txt", "r" ,encoding='utf8',errors="ignore")
questionsList = [(line.strip()).title().split() for line in questions]

for sentences in questionsList:
    for words in sentences:
       if words in stopwordsList:
#How to replace the found word with a lowercase version of it?
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: you have to use `string.upper()` and `string.lower()`

Comment: It would be as easy as words.lower()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257094/how-to-change-a-string-into-uppercase

Answer (score 0):

In python you can turn a word into lowercase using a built-in function just as follows:

```
string = 'WORD'
string.lower()
```

if you string is all upercase (WORD) it will become (word) and if it contains uppers and lowers (WoRd) it will also become (word)

Comment: The issue with that is that its not getting saved in the stopwordsList. Maybe because this string is in a List?

Comment: Create  a new list and then if the word is in uppercase turn it to lower then append it to the list , else just append it straight away

Comment: Append would work? 

This is a sentence where i´m checking for stopwords to convert them to lower case
['What', "Men'S", 'Body', 'Wash', 'Smells', 'The', 'Best'], ['What', 'Is', 'The', 'Best', 'Body', 'Wash'],

Comment: You can create a variable which is a string and then after your list is finished you can do `your_string_var.join (your_list_var)` and you will get a string

Comment: what do you think about using enumerate to get a index for the insert method?

Comment: I dont know .. I think it may work

Answer (score 0):

Python Strings have an in-built `string.lower()` method that returns the String in lower case (there's also a `string.upper()` method as well as a `string.swapcase()` method, both return a string in the desired case)

Answer (score 0):

use the string method `string.lower()`.
from the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.lower#str.lower):

```
str.lower()
Return a copy of the string with all the cased characters 4 converted to lowercase.

The lowercasing algorithm used is described in section 3.13 of the Unicode Standard.
```

Example :

```py
>>> 'HELLO WORLD'.lower()
'hello world'
>>> 'HeLLo WorLD'.lower()
'hello world'
```

In your code:

```py
# List of Stopwords
import os
import codecs
# open working directory
stopwords = open("C:\\Python Project\\Headings Generator\\stopwords.txt", "r" ,encoding='utf8',errors="ignore")

stopwordsList = [(line.strip()).title() for line in stopwords]

questions = open("C:\\Python Project\\Headings Generator\\questionslist.txt", "r" ,encoding='utf8',errors="ignore")
questionsList = [(line.strip()).title().split() for line in questions]

for sentences in questionsList:
    for words in sentences:
       if words in stopwordsList:
           words = words.lower()
```

I also give you this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-do-i-lowercase-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I tried it this way but when I print the question list it looks like the stopwords are untouched.

https://www.screencast.com/t/1SLNyewf

Comment: can I see stopwordlist ?