# Text Game - Convert input text to lowercase - Python 3.0

Tags: python, text, input, lowercase

((In response to the above edit, this was not answered in the above link. The above question is irrelevant to my intended use.))

I have read a similar question about turning a string into lowercase;

*[How to convert string to lowercase in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-to-convert-string-to-lowercase-in-python)*

I understand how this works perfectly, however my attempts at this myself have failed.

Here's my current setup example for a debug block;

```
#Debug block - Used to toggle the display of variable data throughout the game for debug purposes.
def debug():
    print("Would you like to play in Debug/Developer Mode?")
    while True:
        global egg
        choice = input()
        if choice == "yes":
            devdebug = 1
            break
        elif choice == "Yes":
            devdebug = 1
            break
        elif choice == "no":
            devdebug = 0
            break
        elif choice == "No":
            devdebug = 0
            break
        elif choice == "bunny":
            print("Easter is Here!")
            egg = 1
            break
        else:
            print("Yes or No?")
 #
```

So, I have it prewritten to work with a different capitalization. However, I'd like to use only one `if` statement per word rather than using two for the capitalization. I do have an idea, that uses another block to determine a True of False state, which would look like this;

```
def debugstate():
    while True:
        global devstate
        choice = input()
        if choice == "Yes":
            devstate = True
            break
        elif choice == "yes":
            devstate = True
            break
        elif choice == "No":
            devstate = False
            break
#Etc Etc Etc
```

But using this block would just take the lines of code I *already* have, and move it somewhere else. I know I could set it up that if it isn't 'Yes' then the else can automatically set devstate to 0, but I prefer to have a more controlled environment. I don't want to accidentally type 'yes ' with a space and have devmode off.

So back to the question;

How would I make it so I can just do the following?

```
def debug():
    print("Debug Mode?")
    while True:
        global egg
        choice = input()
        if choice == "yes" or "Yes":
            devdebug = 1
            break
        elif choice == "no" or "No":
            devdebug = 0
            break
        elif choice == "egg":
            devdebug = 0
            egg = 1
            print("Easter is Here")
            break
        else:
            print("Yes or No?")
#
```

The above code probably isn't the best example, but it at least helps me get my point across when I say I only want one `if` statement per word. (Also, I hope I didn't just solve my own problem here xD.)

So, how would I do this?

((Also, the reason I go here rather than the Python forums is because I prefer to ask my question in my own way rather than trying to piece together an answer from a question that was worded differently for someone else.))

Comment: _"I understand how this works perfectly, however my attempts at this myself have failed"_. I would be interested in seeing the code where you tried to use `.lower`.

Comment: just use if choice.lower() == "yes" and you're done

Comment: @Kevin It was the placement of .lower that confused me. "How to convert string to lowercase in python" for me, didn't shout out to me where I would put .lower

Comment: @Wooble I looked at that question and it did Not help me in anyway.

Comment: @GameWylder You couldn't see that your `choice == "yes" or "Yes"` condition is effectively `(choice == "yes") or ("Yes")` - where the `"Yes"` part will _always_ evaluate as `True` - after reading a question with solutions explaining exactly why that's not the way to write what you wanted?

Comment: @MatthewTrevor Im very particular about how I word questions. Also I understand the Boolean functions properly, the only thing I needed help with is formatting it properly.

Comment: Your understanding of how conditions are evaluated isn't evident in your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using .lower() is your best option

```
choice = input()
choice = choice.lower()
if choice == 'yes':
    dev_debug = 1
    break
```

Or use 'in'

```
choice = input()
if choice in ('yes', 'Yes'):
    dev_debug = 1
    break
```

Comment: I tried the first example, and it worked perfectly! And thanks for the second example, it's definitely something I'll use in the future. Thank you again or showing the proper setup.

Comment: @GameWylder The second example is _exactly_ the same as the accepted solution to the question Wooble linked you to.

Answer (score 2):

You may put a lowercased value in some variable and use that instead of original `choice` where you don't care about case and you can still use `choice` where the case is significant:

```
def debug():
    print("Debug Mode?")
    while True:
        global egg
        choice = input()
        lowchoice = choice.lower()
        if lowchoice == "yes":
            devdebug = 1
            break
        elif lowchoice == "no":
            devdebug = 0
            break
        elif choice == "egg":
            devdebug = 0
            egg = 1
            print("Easter is Here")
            break
        else:
            print("Yes or No?")
```

Answer (score 0):

One word answer: string.lower()

To find out what variables/methods are available for a class/object, just use dir(object/class/method())

For e.g.

```
a="foo"
type(a)
<type 'str'>
dir(a)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```