# Prompt user for y, yes, n, or no

Tags: python, user-input

I need to make sure that all the conditions are met, with a special case. The student is still deemed 'eligible' even if either the 'before2010' or 'gerequirements' aren't met.

However, I can't get the program to work properly. I want to be able to type 'y', 'yes', 'n', or 'no' for the answers to the yes/no questions, but it comes off as an error, because I didn't assign 'y' apparently.

```
def main():
    credits = int(input("Enter the total number of credits completed: "))
    udcredits = int(input("Enter the number of upper-division credits completed: "))
    localcredits = int(input("Enter the number of local credits completed: "))
    mrequirements = input("Have you completed all major requirements? ")
    before2010 = eval(input("In what year did you matriculate? "))
    gerequirements = input("Are your general education requirements done? ")

    if before2010 < 2010 and credits >= 120 and udcredits >= 40 and localcredits >= 30 and mrequirements[0] == y:
        print("eligible")
    else:
        print("ineligible")

    if gerequirements[0] == y and credits >= 120 and udcredits >= 40 and localcredits >= 30 and mrequirements[0] == y:
        print("eligible")
    else:
        print("ineligible")
main()
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: also `gerequirements[0] == 'y'` make sure you get the quotes in there. You're probably expecting a string.

Comment: I am using python 3. Setting that with apostrophes got it running, now I'm just stuck on how to make the code do the correct output according to the input answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
gerequirements[0] == y
```

This line will not compile.  If you're trying to match the character `y` you have to wrap it in quotes to denote a string.  Without quotes, Python expects `y` to be a variable.

So the expression becomes:

```
gerequirements[0] == 'y'
```

---

As the commenters have mentioned, there's several other problems with your code:

- Prefer [`raw_input` to `input`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915361/113632).
- [Never use `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/113632), certainly not on user input; in your case you probably want [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).
- You should [lower-case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6797984/113632) your yes/no inputs to allow users to type in upper or lower case.

Answer (score 1):

Your full code would be:

```
def main():
    credits = int(input("Enter the total number of credits completed: "))
    udcredits = int(input("Enter the number of upper-division credits completed: "))
    localcredits = int(input("Enter the number of local credits completed: "))
    mrequirements = input("Have you completed all major requirements? ")
    before2010 = int(input("In what year did you matriculate? "))
    gerequirements = input("Are your general education requirements done? ")

    if before2010 < 2010 and credits >= 120 and udcredits >= 40 and localcredits >= 30 and mrequirements[0].lower() == 'y':
        print("eligible")
    else:
        print("ineligible")

    if gerequirements[0].lower() == 'y' and credits >= 120 and udcredits >= 40 and localcredits >= 30 and mrequirements[0].lower() == 'y':
        print("eligible")
    else:
        print("ineligible")

main()
```

**CHANGES**

- Line 6, changed `eval()` to `int()` safer this way, better practice
- Line 9 & 14 added `.lower()` to **mrequirements[0]** and **gerequirements[0]** so that even if the user typed a capital Y the test woud still pass.
- Line 9 & 14 Added quotes to `"y"` since it's saved as a string from the input() function in Python. Otherwise the `if` statement wouldn't return true

It should run fine now.