# Function to count upper/lower case letters

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

Could you please help me with writing a function to count alphabetic characters. My current output for this code is like this:

It contains 5 alphabetic characters of which 4 ( 80.0 %) are 'h'

My output for this code should be like this:
It contains 5 alphabetic characters of which 5 ( 100.0 %) are 'h'. I would like to treat both upper/lowercase letters equally

```
def count(p):
    lows = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    ups =  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    numberOfh = 0
    totalChars = 0
    for achar in p:
        if achar in lows or achar in ups:
            totalChars = totalChars + 1
            if achar == 'h':
                numberOfh = numberOfh + 1

    percent_with_h = (numberOfh / totalChars) * 100
    print("It contains", totalChars, "alphabetic characters of which", numberOfh, "(", percent_with_h, "%)", "are 'h'.")


p = "Hhhhh"
count(p)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string to lowercase in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-to-convert-string-to-lowercase-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `if` statement to

```
if achar == 'h' or achar == 'H':
```

If you want to count all 'h' and 'H'.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. If this solution helped you could you upvote it (if possible)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
print p.lower().count("h")
```

I think should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the occurrence of any letter in your string, rather than just h you could use something like this, which returns a dictionary containing each letter as the key, and the percentage as the value:

```
    def count_alphas(s):
        s = s.lower()
        alpha_set = set(s)
        alpha_counts = {}

        for x in alpha_set: 
            alpha_counts[x] = s.count(x) / float(len(s)) * 100

        return alpha_counts

    # an example use:
    print(count_alphas('thisissomeexampletext'))
```