# python. how to add in .lower().

Tags: python, case-sensitive

```
user1 = "aqa code" 
pass1 = "uzair123"
username = input("Enter username: ")
password = input("Enter password: ")
while username !=  user1:
    print("Access denied: username is incorrect try again ")
    username = input("Enter username again: ")
    if username == user1:
        print("access granted")
        while password != pass1:
            print("Password is still incorrect")
            password=input("Enter password again: ")
            if password == pass1:
                print("Access granted")
while password != pass1:
    print("Access denied,Password is incorrect")
    password=input("Enter password again: ")
    if password == pass1:
        print("Access granted")
```

How do I add a .lower() to the username/user1 so it becomes case insensitive when you type in the answer? Please help.

Comment: You can simply use `username.lower() == user1` instead of `username == user1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string to lowercase in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-to-convert-string-to-lowercase-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.lower` on the return of the input function.

```
username = input("Enter username: ").lower()
password = input("Enter password: ").lower()
```

Comment: *call, not pass. And you don't call it on function but on the string that this function returns.

Comment: the code doesnt carry on for some reason if i do that

Comment: python 2.7 or 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `.lower()` is indeed the solution you're looking for, but you may want to try to simplify your flow a bit, so you have fewer places to edit whenever you want to modify your input statement. To do this I would suggest creating a variable for each loop that is initially false and only get user input once inside each loop:

```
loop_condition = False  #initialize loop condition
while not loop_condition:  #loop until we say so
    value = input("please enter a value: ")  #human input
    value = value.lower() #convert to lower case for comparison
    if value == "password":  #test
        print("success")
        loop_condition = True  #loop will terminate when we hit our `while` again
    else:
        print("fail")
print("rest of program goes here")
```

Here you can see we only call `input()` once, and only have to convert it to lowercase in one place as well. Simplicity is always your friend.

**note: use `raw_input()` if you're using python 2.7**