# Using a regular expression to replace characters

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove all characters except `a-z`, `A-Z`, and spaces from a title. I then want to convert all the characters to lower case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Next time, please take a look at our ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: If regex is not mandotory, use the good `.lower` [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.lower#str.lower), related So question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-to-convert-string-to-lowercase-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module.

```
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z ]', '', my_string).lower()
```

Here's an example:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z ]', '', 'This is 1 test string; I like it.').lower()
'this is  test string i like it'
```

Comment: should be `r'[^a-z A-Z]'` yours will remove the spaces as well which the OP wants to keep

Comment: @officialaimm: You are correct.