# when the if statement checks 'coffee' or 'c' I want is to also be able to check all forms of those too. I.e CofFeE should work but not cofe

Tags: python

```
coffeortea = input("Would you like coffee or tea? ")
if 'coffee' == coffeortea:
    print("1")
elif 'c' == coffeortea:
    print("2")
else:
    print("3")
```

I would like it if the user types coFfeE to print 1. or if the user types C to type 2. Basically, I want upper and lower case to not be an issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string to lowercase in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-to-convert-string-to-lowercase-in-python)

Comment: force the checks to do `str.lower()`

Answer (score 2):

Compare on the if clauses everything uppercase or lowercase

```
coffeortea = input("Would you like coffee or tea? ")
if 'coffee' == coffeortea.lower():
    print("1")
elif 'c' == coffeortea.lower():
    print("2")
else:
    print("3")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can receive your input with properly convertion to `str`, with `lower()` function call, and then, make your condition basing on that:

```
coffeortea = str(raw_input("Would you like coffee or tea? ")).lower()
if 'coffee' == coffeortea:
    print("1")
elif 'c' == coffeortea:
    print("2")
else:
    print("3")
```