# How to convert the input into lowercase

Tags: python

I would like to know, what can I do so that even if the answers are uppercase it still marks the points? I am a new python user...

```
colleges = ["MIT", "UAB", "Harvard", "UA", "Standford"]
votes = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Q1 = input("What is important in your future?\na)Invent something important\nb)Helping other people\nc)Know everything\nd)A job that I love\ne)Make the world better\n")
if (Q1 == "a"):
  votes[0] = votes[0]+1
elif (Q1 == "b"):
  votes[1] = votes[1]+1
elif (Q1 == "c"):
  votes[2] = votes[2]+1
elif (Q1 == "d"):
  votes[3] = votes[3]+1
elif (Q1 == "e"):
  votes[4] == votes[4]+1
```

Comment: Use `Q1.lower()`

Comment: `if Q1.lower() == 'a':` and similar for the other cases

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-do-i-lowercase-a-string-in-python

Comment: You should also check for "none of the above" and prompt the user to try again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Q1 = input("What is...").lower()`