# Why Python if "String" in UserInput: Always works no matter what i enter at UserInput?

Tags: python, input, user-input

I am trying to make an simple python Rock, Paper, Scissors, game. Here is my entire code.

```
import random

# The AI Respond, will be random.

print('Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors Game! \n')

UserInput = input("Please enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors, to start the game. \n")

BotChoicelist = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors", "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors", "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
BotAwnser = random.sample(BotChoicelist, 1)

UserScore = 0

#If1
if "Rock" or "rock" in UserInput:
    if "Rock" in BotAwnser:
        print("Bot choose Rock, Tie")
    if "Paper" in BotAwnser:
        print("Bot choose Paper, Bot won.")
        print("Your score is:")
        print(UserScore - 1)
    if "Scissors" in BotAwnser:
        print("Bot choose Scissors, You won.")
        print("Your score is:")
        print(UserScore + 1)
   
#if2
if "Paper" or "paper" in UserInput:
    if "Paper" in BotAwnser:
        print("Bot choose Paper, Tie")
    if "Scissors" in BotAwnser:
        print("Bot choose Scissors, Bot won.")
        print("Your score is:")
        print(UserScore - 1)
    if "Rock" in BotAwnser:
        print("Bot choose Rock, You won.")
        print("Your score is:")
        print(UserScore + 1)
```

The problem is no matter what i enter at UserInput it will start the If1 and If2, how can i fix that?
To be more clear here is the output:

```
Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors Game! 

Please enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors, to start the game. 
AnyThingHere
Bot choose Scissors, You won.
Your score is:
1
Bot choose Scissors, Bot won. 
Your score is:
-1
```

Comment: you must check what then input is and write an exit or return statement so that program wont continue from that point.

Answer (score 0):

```
if UserInput in ["rock","Rock"]:
   #do something 
#if2
elif str(UserInput).lower() in ["paper"]:
  #do soemthing else
elif (another expression)
```

Please search the web for `control-flow` and logic statements

Answer (score 0):

```
if "Rock" or "rock" in UserInput:
```

does not do what you think it does.

It does not check if either `"Rock"` or `"rock"` are substrings of `UserInput`. Instead, it checks if `"Rock"` is true, or if `"rock"` is a substring of `UserInput`.

`"Rock"` is a 'truthy' value, meaning that in practice your if condition becomes:

```
if True or "rock" in UserInput:
```

which can be simplified to

```
if True:
```

So your `if` statement doesn't really do anything at all.

Changing the condition to something like `if "Rock" in UserInput or "rock" in UserInput:` will help, but you may want to look into [`lower()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-do-i-lowercase-a-string-in-python), in order to simplify the condition.