# How to make a script case insensitive (Python Coin Flipper)

Tags: python, python-3.x, case-sensitive

I am writing a heads or tails guessing program.

I am trying to figure out how to make the input that the user gives case insensitive and I've tried `.upper()` and `.lower()` and I'm just not sure how to do it.

```
import random
coin = ['Heads', 'Tails']
guess_count = 0
while guess_count <= 5:
    flip = random.choice(coin)
    guess = input("Guess Heads or Tails? ")
    guess_count += 1
    if guess_count == 5:
        print("Out of attempts")
        break
    elif guess == 'Quit':
        break
    elif guess == flip:
        print(f"It was {flip} good job!")
        print(f"You got it in {guess_count} attempt(s).")
        break
    else:
        if guess != flip:
            print("Try again!")
            print(f"Guess Count: {guess_count}")
print("Game Over!")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I lowercase a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-do-i-lowercase-a-string-in-python)

Comment: set ```guess = guess.lower()``` after input to enforce lower case for the user input

Answer (score 1):

Try using `capitalize()` It will make your string to have first letter capital only.

Try:

```
import random
coin = ['Heads', 'Tails'] 
guess_count = 0
while guess_count <= 5:
    flip = random.choice(coin)
    guess = input("Guess Heads or Tails? ").capitalize() #<--here
    guess_count += 1
    if guess_count == 5:
        print("Out of attempts")
        break
    elif guess == 'Quit':
        break
    elif guess == flip:
        print(f"It was {flip} good job!")
        print(f"You got it in {guess_count} attempt(s).")
        break
    else:
        if guess != flip:
            print("Try again!")
            print(f"Guess Count: {guess_count}")
print("Game Over!")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
coin = ['Heads', 'Tails']
```

you made the decision that your choices are `Heads` and `Tails`, with a capital letter. The user will have to enter it exactly that way.

Using `.lower()` and `.upper()` will work - but (!) you have to do so on both sides. That is:

```
elif guess.lower() == flip.lower():
```

Usually, one would avoid that on one side by defining

```
coin = ['heads', 'tails']    # Note the lower casing
[...]
elif guess.lower() == flip:  # no lower casing needed on flip
```

But, if you want the output of `print()` to have exactly that casing, just use `lower()` or `upper()` on both sides of the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
coin = ['heads', 'tails']
guess = input("Guess Heads or Tails? ").lower()
```

You should also have something to check if the input are correct.

example for a simular flip a coin program:

```
import random

coin = ['heads', 'tails']
number_of_guesses = 5
coin_flip = random.choice(coin)
guesses=0
while (guesses<5):
    guess = input('Guess Heads or Tails? ').lower()
    if(guess==coin_flip):
        print(f'Correct, it was {coin_flip}')
        break
    elif(guess not in coin):
        guesses += 1
        print(f'wrong input, number of remainding guesses {number_of_guesses-guesses}')  
    
    else:
        guesses += 1
        print(guesses)
        if(guesses!=number_of_guesses):
            print(f'guess again, number of remainding guesses {number_of_guesses-guesses}')

if(guesses == number_of_guesses):
    print('you have failed')
```

This could also be solved recursivly/with a for loop, if you are interested in learning

Answer (score 0):

You could also use casefold(), it is there to for caseless comparisons.
And also the last "if" statement is not necessary

```
else:
     print("Try again!")
     print(f"Guess Count: {guess_count}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Input is converted to lowercase
guess = input("Guess Heads or Tails? ").lower()
```

or

```
# Input is converted to uppercase
guess = input("Guess Heads or Tails? ").upper()
```

Use .lower() though, its easier imo