# How do I change the value of a variable to lowercase in Python?

Tags: python, function, variables, uppercase, lowercase

How do I change the value of a variable to lowercase in Python?

For example, when "I study Python programming at KAIST Center for Gift Education." is the value of this variable, how do i make it "i study python programming at kaist center for gifted education"?

Comment: nonono not that i want all of them to lowercase

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me this basic data manipulation" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
This is trivial to look up; doing so is *your* job, not a valid question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I lowercase a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-do-i-lowercase-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `lower` function

```
string.lower()
```

And here is the [official documents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.lower#str.lower).

Comment: how do i use that in code? my code is 
sentence = 'I study Python programming at KAIST Center For Gifted Education.'

# Initialise counters:
vowels = {
    'a': 0,
    'e': 0,
    'i': 0,
    'o': 0,
    'u': 0,
}
#
for char in sentence:
    if char in vowels:
        vowels[char] += 1

print(vowels['a'])

print(vowels['e'])

print(vowels['i'])

print(vowels['o'])

print(vowels['u'])

Comment: @Aiden that's another question, but if you need to count occurrence of some characters in the string you can use `count` function. first convert sentence to lower case and then: for char in vowels:
    vowels[char] = sentence.count(char)

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `.replace()` and `.lower()`

```
stringEx = stringEx.lower()
```

output

```
i study python programming at kaist center for gift education.
```

Comment: The whole sentence is the variable so no need to replace, just store .lower().

Comment: my bad didn't see that

Comment: ok i'll try that thx for advice