# How to convert to lower case string if it's in upper case

Tags: python

I'm writing this function to detect if two strings are anagrams. I want to convert the strings into lower case characters in case one of the characters is in upper case, but what I wrote doesn't seem to be working properly.

```
# function to check if two strings areanagram or not
def eh_anagrama(cad1, cad2):
    if cad1.islower() == False:
        cad1.lower()
    if cad2.islower() == False:
        cad2.lower()
    if(sorted(cad1)== sorted(cad2)):
        print("The strings are anagrams.")
    else:
        print("The strings aren't anagrams.")
```

Comment: Please give a [mre], _"doesn't seem to be working properly"_ isn't much help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I lowercase a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-do-i-lowercase-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check if they're lower, as they would be compared in lower case anyway:

```
def eh_anagrama(cad1, cad2):
    if sorted(cad1.lower()) == sorted(cad2.lower()):
        print("The strings are anagrams.")
    else:
        print("The strings aren't anagrams.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `cad1.lower()` will convert this string to lowercase, but this value isn't used, you could try `cad1 = cad1.lower()`

Edit:
Also, it's more "pythonic" using `if not cad1.islower()` as opposed to `if cad1.islower() == False`

Comment: On "more Pythonic" not to compare to `False`, that's true (PEP 8 specifically discourages it), but in this particular case, there's hardly any reason to even perform the test; saving a perhaps unnecessary string allocation at the expense of scanning the string twice when you need to lowercase it anyway is pretty pointless.

Comment: okok, thanks for the tip, I'm still a bit of a noob, learning step by step!

Comment: @ShadowRanger this comment should probably be in your own answer

Answer (score 0):

Just unconditionally convert, and *reassign* the lowercased string (`str` are immutable, so methods return new strings, they don't change the one they're called on):

```
def eh_anagrama(cad1, cad2):
    cad1 = cad1.lower()  # Reassign to replace with lowercased string
    cad2 = cad2.lower()  # Ditto
    if sorted(cad1) == sorted(cad2):
        print("The strings are anagrams.")
    else:
        print("The strings aren't anagrams.")
```

Minor side-note: For handling non-English alphabets more correctly, I'd suggest using `.casefold()` instead of `.lower()`; in other languages, this can make a meaningful difference.

Comment: That's also quite helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes. Instead of just writing `cad1.lower()` or `cad2.lower()` I assigned them to the variable corresponding to the value.

`cad1 = cad1.lower()` and `cad2 = cad2.lower()`

```
# function to check if two strings areanagram or not
def eh_anagrama(cad1, cad2):

    cad1 = cad1.lower() ; cad2 = cad2.lower()

    if sorted(cad1) == sorted(cad2):
        print("The strings are anagrams.")
    else:
        print("The strings aren't anagrams.")
```

Comment: No need to check if it's lower before converting to lower case

Comment: Good point, lemme edit