# Search CSV for case insensitive duplicates?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv that looks something like this:

file.csv

```
name,apptype
AppABC,python
appabc,python
AppABB,python
AppABA,python
Appaba,python
```

I need to figure out a way to determine if any "name" exists as a case insensitive duplicate and report back the results.

In this case I should know that the following are duplicates:

```
AppABC,python
appabc,python
AppABA,python
Appaba,python
```

This is what I was trying, but it's not working.

```
with open(appcsv_path) as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

for name in csv_reader:
    re.findall(name, csv_reader, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

This results in an error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Using the Pandas method below but editing it for "Name" not "name":

```
    df = pd.read_csv(appcsv_path)
out = df[df.Name.str.strip().str.lower().duplicated(keep=False)].loc[0:0]
print(out.to_string(index=False))
```

Results in:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, Type]
Index: []
```

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, generally comparing strings without case sensitivity, you [lowercase the strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-do-i-lowercase-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Updated the question with what I tried in hopes of solving it but it was a long shot. I don't fully understand what I'm doing with python, I just know enough to copy and paste things from stackoverflow and sometimes get lucky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pandas solution using `duplicated`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(appcsv_path)
out = df[df.name.str.strip().str.lower().duplicated(keep=False)].loc[:,'name']
```

##### Output :

which will give you the expected output

```
print(out.to_string(index=False))
```

```
AppABC
appabc
AppABA
Appaba
```

or to keep both the columns you can do

```
out = df[df.name.str.strip().str.lower().duplicated(keep=False)]
print(out.to_string(index=False))
```

which gives you

```
  name apptype
AppABC  python
appabc  python
AppABA  python
Appaba  python
```

Comment: to test this out I need to import pandas right?

Comment: yes @ddevalco `import pandas as pd`

Comment: import pandas as pd right ?

Comment: Humm... I'm getting AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: What's the column name in you case for name? Can you print `df.columns` and show me

Comment: i would think its name, the csv starts with "name,apptype" so I assumed that would mean name would be the column name, wonder if I can just do location 0 since its always the first column

Comment: No I was trying a few things before emailing you.

Comment: The solution is pretty simple, should work for you without any issue, mail me I can take a look at it

Comment: Email sent. Thanks