# How do I fix my code so that it does repeat count a word?

Tags: python

So, my code reads a poem from a file. It then counts the number of time a word occurs and adds to a dictionary. However, my code repeats the words and counts separately.

Here is my code:

```
def unique_word_count(file):
    words = open(file, "r")
    lines = words.read()
    words = lines.split()
    counts = dict()

    for word in words:
        if word in counts:
            counts[word] += 1
        else:
            counts[word] = 1

    return counts
```

For, example if we have the string, `"Hi, hi, hi how are you"`:
The output for my code would come out as:

```
{"Hi":1, "hi":1, "hi":1, "how":1, "are":1, "you":1}
```

While it should come out as:

```
{"hi":3, "how":1, "are":1, "you":1}
```

How can I fix my code so that it does not repeat words?
Thank you!

Comment: Note that indenting only the first line doesn't format your code correctly. Use code blocks (indent ALL code by 4 spaces) or code fences (three backticks `\`\`\`` on the lines before and after your code) [Formatting help](/help/formatting)

Comment: The output you claim to obtain is impossible -- Keys in a dict are unique, so it is not possible for a dict to have two `"hi"` keys. You probably got `{"Hi": 1, "hi":2, "how":1, "are":1, "you":1}`, but if you truly understand how your code works, combining those two `"hi"` values should be trivially easy using `str.lower`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I lowercase a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-do-i-lowercase-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Hello, I understand combining the "Hi" and "hi" but my code actually does counts the two "hi" separately. Not sure why.

Comment: Look at your dictionary carefully. The first two keys contain a trailing comma, since `.split()` only splits by spaces. Looks like you need a better definition of what a "word" is.

Comment: The string is just an example, the actual poem in the file is very long and I don't think, I could post it entirely here but I could show part of the input and output. Part of the poem, "Row, row, row your boat". The output of my code is, "{"Row": 10, "row": 10, "row": 10, "your": 10,  "boat":10}. Note: the number count is ten because the poem repeats the string multiple times.

Comment: Again, that is not possible. Your dictionary can NOT have two `"row"` keys. It has one `"row"` key, and one `"row,"` key. *Notice the **trailing comma** in the second key*. Now you need to ask how you can remove trailing commas (or periods or other symbols) from a word.

Comment: as an aside, you're currently not closing the file before the function ends, or before you repurpose the variable `words`.  After the line `lines = words.read()` you need to add `words.close()` or change that part of the function to use the file context manager.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're get that output is because of `split`.

`split()` splits the sentence in place where there is a space. So in it treats `hi,` and `hi` differently. So try using this code

```
import re

def word_count(str):
    counts = dict()
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', str.lower())
    for word in words:
        if word in counts:
            counts[word] += 1
        else:
            counts[word] = 1

    return counts

print( word_count('Hi, hi, hi how are you'))
```

The usual way to find words in a string is to use `split`, but that can fail, so you need regular expressions to do this.

`\w -- (lowercase w) matches a "word" character: a letter or digit or underbar [a-zA-Z0-9_].`

After the `findall` function filters the string and pulls out the words while ignoring punctuation, it returns the list.

Edit: Added explanation

Comment: A good answer should also include what it is that makes this code work over the original

Comment: Added the explanation

Comment: _"..., but this can fail_": in what situation?  _"findall function filters the string"_: Not really, `findall` finds all matches to the given regex. Why did you give it that regex though? That is the important idea in your answer that needs explanation.