# Read in a CSV file in lower case with Python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, map-function

I'm reading a CSV file into a namedtuple as so:

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple

#So we can handle bad CSV files gracefully
def unfussy_reader(reader):
    while True:
        try:
            yield next(reader.lower())

        # This is a bad row that has an error in it (csv.Error)
        # Alternately it may be a line that doesn't map to the structure we've been given (TypeError)
        except (csv.Error, TypeError):
            pass

        continue

# Create the CSV reader object
csv_reader = csv.reader(file_stream, delimiter=' ', quotechar='"', escapechar='^')

# Set up the named tuple
csvline = namedtuple('csv_line', 'field1, field2, field3')

# Create the named tuple mapping object
map_to_tuple = map(csvline._make, csv_reader)

for line in unfussy_reader(map_to_tuple):
    # do stuff
```

This works well, but my problem is - I want all of the content of the CSV to be read in lower-case. As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801668/convert-a-python-list-with-strings-all-to-lowercase-or-uppercase), a simple lambda would do it:
`map(lambda x:x.lower(),["A","B","C"])`
but I can't find anywhere to put it before the data ends up in the tuple (and thus unchaneable).

Is there a way to do this within this structure (Python 3.5)?

Comment: Add a line before `csv_reader = ...` that does: `file_stream = (line.lower() for line in file_stream)`?

Comment: @bbayles - that worked, although I had to assign it to something and then change the `csv_reader = ` line to point at that rather than `file_stream`. Post it as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the `lower` transform to the stream before you create a CSV reader for it.

```
lower_stream = (line.lower() for line in file_stream)
csv_reader = csv.reader(lower_stream, delimiter=' ', quotechar='"', escapechar='^')
```

The parentheses around the `lower_stream` assignment target designate a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). It will not use up `file_stream` and will not pull all of `file_stream` into memory.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(map(lambda line:line.lower(),file_stream), delimiter=' ', quotechar='"', escapechar='^')
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most relevant approach for the asker's use-case, but for others who found this question based on the title, here is a solution using Pandas and converters. It's ideal for csv files with mixed data types. Note that if you specify `converters` and `dtype`, it will override data type specs.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    "./data/mydata.csv",
    converters={"col2": lambda x: x.lower()},
)
```