# how to lower case a list in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read a text file in jupyter notebook and fetch the unique words in the file.

I am reading that file as a list and then trying to apply lower case on it. But the `.lower()` function doesn't work with a list. Please help with the same.

Comment: dont read it as a `list` then ... what does that even mean?

Comment: My guess is the OP is reading the file as a list of lines, perhaps with `readlines()`. Is that right @Naveen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a list of values in val you can do this:

```
valsLower = [item.lower() for item in vals]
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked...!!!

Comment: @Amorpheuses : I am not sure why you were down voted on this answer. From what I can see it answer the question and it also helped me solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote