# How to capitalize each word of a given list of strings?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I need to satisfy this test:

```
def test_capitalize_names():
    assert ["James"] == capitalize_names(["JAMES"])
    assert ["Harry", "Jack"] == capitalize_names(["HArry", "jack"])
```

I tried writing `capitalize_names` like so:

```
def capitalize_names(input):
    input = map(lambda s: s.capitalize(), input)
    li = map(lambda x: '"'+x+'"', input)
    return li
```

It is returning `['"James"']` but I want it to return `["James"]` to satisfy the assert statements and I cannot use any control statements.

Comment: Don't use Python built-in keywords and function names as your variable names. Change `input` to something else. Also, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801668/convert-a-python-list-with-strings-all-to-lowercase-or-uppercase and many other similar questions is SO

Comment: You  can use `str.capitalize` instead of `lambda s: s.capitalize()`.

Comment: The line `li = map(lambda x: '"'+x+'"', my_input)` adds quotation marks to your capitalized string. Why are you surprised that the string has the quotation marks? Remove that line. From Python's point of view, `"` and `'` serve the same purpose.

Comment: i cannot use str.capitalize() since it is a list

Comment: But please read my comment. I said: use `str.capitalize` instead of `lambda s: s.capitalize()`. Just that: `my_input = map(str.capitalize, my_input)`. It makes your code 40% faster. Not using `map` (use list comprehension instead) makes it another 20% faster.

Comment: in list of strings ["james"] is not equal to ['james']

Comment: i removed that line and made it str.capitalize but now i want the code to satisfy assert the statement please help and thnk you for the suggestions

Comment: Did you try `["james"]==['james']`? The two lists (and strings) are exactly the same.

Comment: i tried but it is still showing an error

Comment: thank you for your suggestions

Comment: @marshmallow, for input like `['KEn watson']`, what do you expect? `['Ken Watson']` or `['Ken watson']`.

Comment: The **original problem** here was **caused by a typo**. Questions should not be edited to ask a new question - the accepted answer was based on the code that I have restored in this edit. OP then edited to include the new working code and inappropriately ask a new question about getting a result `["James"]` rather than `['James']` - however, this **does not make sense**, because those **are the same thing** (and the `assert` would succeed in this case). Either way, there is not a reproducible problem in this question, and it should be closed and deleted.

Comment: For the question described in the title - which is **not what OP was asking** - we have many superior duplicates, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def capitalize_names(input):
    return list(map(lambda s: s.capitalize(), input))
```

this is the efficient way of doing this.

Comment: It is bad to use variable name as **input**. The statements like `m = input;` works perfect and gives `<built-in function input>`.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is:

```
def capitalize_names(inp):
    return [i.capitalize() for i in inp]
def test_capitalize_names():
    assert ["James"] == capitalize_names(["JAMES"])
    assert ["Harry", "Jack"] == capitalize_names(["HArry", "jack"])
```

Comment: This is the most efficient implementation (timewise).

Comment: i cannot use any control statements

Comment: @marshmallow What do you mean by control statements?

Comment: @marshmallow My answer is much faster then mehrdad-pedramfar's answer

Answer (score 1):

A more succinct way: for example:

```
import string
def capitalize_names(lst_str):
    return map(string.capitalize, lst_str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print capitalize_names(["HArry", "jack", "JAMES"])
    # ['Harry', 'Jack', 'James']
```